# Android and libusb. How to access USB?

Tags: android, libusb

I try to use libusb in my [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) project. I can use some libusb functions (such as libusb_init, libusb_get_device_list, etc.), but when I try to execute libusb_open I get LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCES. I have performed the all tips from the libusb documentation (added /dev/bus/usb/*/* into ueventd.rc, got the root into application, got permissions in Java), but nothing helped me.

I have the rooted the Android device (odroid-xu).

Comment: Do you have USB host in your device?

Comment: Of cause. And I already have written the java app, but the data exchange is not fast enough, so I want to use ndk and libusb.

Comment: Did you prove that the bottleneck is Java?

Comment: I guess the size of the buffer. I get data by chunks which max size is 16384 bytes.

Comment: so what's the problem with using Java?

Comment: While I read data from usb device, it will be overwritten by the following.

Comment: "got the root into application" suggests a conceptual error - root only (at most) applies to helper executables, never an application process itself.

Comment: But how can I get access?